# PostgreSQL client -- How To Start It?

Tags: postgresql

I just installed PostgreSQL-8.4 on Ubuntu. How do I start it / its GUI, connect to a database etc? I know `SQL`, but can't find `PostgreSQL`'s icon in my Ubuntu 10.04 desktop (hence, am not sure how to start it).

Comment: For windows, read [install]/postgresql/9.3/doc/postgresql/html/server-start.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Postgresql has no built in gui.

to check if it is running run the following from a terminal

```
ps aux | grep postgres
```

You can use psql to access from the command line.

to install psql

```
aptitude install postgresql-client
```

then to run

```
psql -h dbhost -U username dbname
```

If you want a gui intall package pgadmin

```
aptitude install pgadmin3
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to run `psql` from the command line and am getting the following error: `psql: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "davis"`

Comment: Here is a decent tutorial, notice the info about the pg_hba.conf, that will be important to edit if you want to access remotely

Comment: thank you. Where is the `pg_hba.conf` file? I keep getting this error: `psql: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "davis"`

Comment: I believe it is under /etc/postgresql with the aptitude installed version. I have none around to check for sure though.

Comment: Ubuntu 13/10: sudo -u postgres psql . Then \c in the interactive shell results in "You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres".

Answer (score 8):

I start postgres prompt by using the following command:

```
 sudo -u postgres psql
```

I use Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 7):

If you're a Mac user, try running this

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

then do

```
psql
```

Answer (score 1):

you may start by firing up a graphical client. In a terminal type : pgadmin3

You will be presented with the pgAdmin III interface. Click on the "Add a connection to a server" button (top left). In the new dialog, enter the address 127.0.0.1, a description of the server, the default database ("mydb" in the example above), your username ("postgres") and your password.

With this GUI you may start creating and managing databases, query the database, execute SQl etc.

check out - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL